# F# error FS0597 possibly caused by incorrect indentation

Tags: f#, whitespace, indentation, f#-3.0

I have the following piece of code:

```
if File.Exists(settingsFilePath) = false then
    System.Console.WriteLine("Are you running BlogDotNet for the first time? (yes/no):");
    match System.Console.ReadLine() with
    | "yes" -> 
    try
      ()
    with
      | :? System.UnauthorizedAccessException -> System.Console.WriteLine("You don't have write permissions on the current directory, please move to another one!")
      | :? System.IOException -> System.Console.WriteLine("Couldn't one or more of the create the necessary directories and files, an unknown IO related exception occured")
    | "no" -> System.Console.WriteLine("Then you must be running blogctl while in a wrong directory,")
                  System.Console.WriteLine("please move to the correct directory first before attempting to issue any further blogctl commands")
    | _ -> System.Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer, please answer with either 'yes' or 'no'")
  else
    match List.ofArray (System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().[1..]) with 
    | [""] | ["help"] | ["--help"] | ["-h"] -> ()
    | _ -> System.Console.WriteLine("Invalid command or command with invalid arguments, run 'blogctl help' to get a list of the available commands")
             System.Console.WriteLine("and information about their usage")
```

The compiler keeps complaining with "error FS0597: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized" at the last line and at line 12. Now as you can see at the code listing above those lines are indeed incorrectly indented, but when I copied them from my editor (Visual Studio Code) they *were* correctly indented. I have tried multiple times to remove the indentation and indent them again, to no avail, the compiler just keeps complaining. When I put the 2 Console.WriteLine() expressions on one line after the arrow and separate them by a semicolon the compiler stops complaining.

Comment: I think aligning the `S` in `System` should work.

Comment: The problem is when I paste the code in the listing in a text editor the expressions *are* aligned for some mysterious reason ;)

Comment: Check what the whitespace characters actually are - Maybe some weird unicode?

Comment: Weird... I just opened the file in TextMate and it did show the indentation was off! So I corrected it and now the compiler doesn't complain anymore! This definitely editor-related.

Comment: Could it be that you have a mix of tabs and spaces in the same file?